# Mixitup jQuery and Option Select Dropdown Menu

Tags: java, html, css

This is probably a pretty quick fix but I seem to not grasp the idea as I'm a bit rusty with javascript.

UPDATE: Here is what I'm trying to do

http://jsfiddle.net/dimerbox/5aQJQ/

```
$(function() {
    $('#Grid').mixitup();
});
```

to work with

```
<div class="controls">
    <label>Select Box
        <select>
            <option value="RedFlowers">Red</option>
            <option value="PinkFlowers">Pink</option>
            <option value="YellowFlowers">Yellow</option>
            <option value="GreenFlowers">Green</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

Not sure how to integrate the Select Dropdown Menu into the script so it will sort for me instead of just the li's that are provided in the boilerplate.

Sorry new to this should have posted a jsfiddle example :)

Thanks again,
dimerbox

Comment: What error are you getting, exactly?

Comment: it will not sort or show any pictures once I try and put in the ID figured it would better to start scratch with boilerplate

Comment: let me get a jsfiddle up probably easier for everybody sorry!!